# Circular Reference in Unity Tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity so I was watching some tutorials and in one of them they did this pattern:

**GameController.cs**

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    [HideInInspector] public RoomNavigation roomNavigation;

    void Awake()
    {
        roomNavigation = GetComponent<RoomNavigation>();
    }
}
```

**RoomNavigation.cs**

```
public class RoomNavigation: MonoBehaviour {

    GameController controller;

    void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<GameController>();
    }
}
```

To me this seems like a pretty obvious case of circular reference but seeing as it was on one of their official tutorial I think I might be missing something about `GetComponent`. Can someone clarify as to if it is circular reference and if so, why would they teach it this way?

Comment: It doesn't appear to match the definition of a (Circular Reference)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference] to me. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Enigmativity If I understand it right, `GameController` will have `roomNavigation` which itself will have a reference to `GameController` which in itself will have a reference to `roomNavigation` and so on.

Comment: Does `GetComponent` get the existing component or create a new one?

Comment: GetComponent gets the existing component. 

If you have 2 separate components that need to know about each other but shouldn't be combined into 1 component (i.e. needing to have the components on separate game objects), then it is perfectly okay to use circular references. In this case there doesn't need to be these separate components, I'm assuming the only reason they are there is to avoid large blobs of code that might confuse viewers.

Comment: Also GetComponent is relatively slow and GameObject.Find and GameObject.FindObjectsOfType are even slower. If you need to access another component multiple times or access it each update frame, then you should store a reference to it.

A common case for circular referencing would be for having a player controller script on the mc, and having scripts on the npcs, that would control their movement, store their health, weapons, change animations etc. These scripts may need to interact with each other (combat, ai pathing, etc.).

Comment: @RishaanGupta Could you show how you would accomplish the same thing as above without the reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is no problem here

Just because ObjectA has a reference to ObjectB and ObjectB *also* has a reference to ObjectA doesn't mean anything beyond "they reference each other."

Computer science has been dealing with [doubly linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) for decades.

#### Does this cause a problem with garbage collection?

No, because GC knows about stuff like this unless it is a naive implementation of GC, but C# .NET has a good (or at least, not naive) GC system. It doesn't check to see if any object *has any references* it works top down: `Main` has a reference to `GameObject` which has a reference `SomeObject`, which has a reference to `ObjectA` which has a reference to `ObjectB`, which has a reference to `ObjectA` (oh, that one's already tracked, move on...).

Among other tactics, such as putting newly created objects in a pool to periodically check for still-alive-ness, and once its been alive for a while, it puts it into a pool of probably-still-alive that gets checked less often. Or using a field called `isDead` that gets marked as true by the class's Deconstructor (this will happen way, way down in the C++ underlying Unity code) that flags an object for the GC.

If both objects become isolated (i.e. their parent Game Object is destroyed), they too, will be destroyed.

#### What about code style or software architecture problems?

Probably. But that's entirely subjective and not on-topic here. Do these two objects HAVE to know about each other? Can they be one object instead? Do these classes have subtypes and are interchangeable?

Keep in mind that `GameObject` knows about `Transform` and `Transform` knows about `GameObject` already, and there's perfectly legitimate reasons for this to be true.

Comment: Wow, I never thought about the `GameObject` and `Transform` relationship and you're completely right about it. Looking at in that way makes it all click.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy There's a few other similar references, but Unity's been moving away from those, with the exception of `GameObject` and `Transform` as all GOs have a Transform and all Transforms have a GO (and all other components have both). Renderers, colliders, and so on used to all have a reference available, but Unity has transitioned to using `GetComponent` for them as not all GOs have those types of components (they were just very common).

Comment: Unity uses assemblies that simply won't allow your project to work if you have circular references. While a lot of projects don't need assemblies, some do, especially when using unit testing.